# Parametrize Queries to prevent SQL Injection

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, parameters

I know that I need to Parametrize my queries, mainly for safety reasons, and I need help doing so. I'm using VB in visual studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012. I have never done this before and everything I find on the web seems unsuited to my particular code. The bit that I think needs work is the following:

objconnection.Open()

```
    strSQL = "insert into dbo.Event(ID, Name, Summary, Date) values (NEWID(), '" & strName & "','" & strSummary & "','" & strLocation & "','" & strDate & "')"
    objcmd = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, objconnection)
    objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    objconnection.Close()
    MsgBox("Event Created", vbMsgBoxSetForeground)
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated. If you need more of the code let me know!

From comments:

I did look at that and tried it but I had problems. At this part:

```
.add(new SqlParameter("@strname", '"& strName &"'))
```

the , between the "@streventname" and '"strName"' is underlined and it says `Expression expected.`

Also

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(cmdText, objconnection)
```

> objconnection gets an error "Value of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.

Probably something stupid I've missed out.

Comment: First link on google: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6bdf8b71-1cf1-41c0-848c-4fca2c9e1ea2/faq-how-do-i-make-a-parameterized-query-in-the-database-with-vbnet

Comment: What did you try that was "unsuited to your particular code"?  Your code seems pretty straightforward.  Build a command, open a connection, execute the command, close the connection, done.  During the "build a command" step you add parameters to the command.

Comment: You might need to explain what is going on with that `NEWID()` function you have in the SQL.

Comment: I did look at that and tried it but I had problems. At this part: 
.add(new SqlParameter("@strname", '"& strName &"'))
the , between the "@streventname" and '"strName"' is underlined and it says Expression expected. Also 
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(cmdText, objconnection)
objconnection gets an error "Value of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.

Probably something stupid i've missed out

Comment: I think he is looking at ways to prevent hackers from using injection.

Comment: LarsTech it creates a UniqueIdentifier (16 digit random identifier) in the database

Comment: We'd like to help, but at this point, you seem to be way in over your head.  If all we do is give you some code that works, it's not going to help you learn anything.  You need to do some research on the basics of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks you for all the help. I managed to solve it. This is what I now have if anyone is interested.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim strName As String = Request.Form("txtName")
        Dim strSummary As String = Request.Form("txtSummary")
        Dim strDate As String = Request.Form("txtDate")

        Dim objconnection As OleDbConnection = Nothing
        Dim objcmd As OleDbCommand = Nothing
        Dim strconnection As String, strSQL As String

        strconnection = "provider=SQLOLEDB;data source=XXX;database=Events;uid=XXX;pwd=XXX;"

        objconnection = New OleDbConnection(strconnection)
        objconnection.ConnectionString = strconnection

        objconnection.Open()

        strSQL = "insert into dbo.CreateApp(ID, Name, Summary, Date)values(NEWID(), ?, ?, ?)"
        objcmd = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, objconnection)
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Name", strName))
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Summary", strSummary))   
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Date", strDate))
        objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        objconnection.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

The key was putting in ?s.

Answer (score 5):

You are mixing your SQL-Objects with your OLEDB-Objects.  Looks like you are using an OLEDB connection, so that means you have to use OLEDB-Objects, so use OleDbCommand instead of SqlCommand, etc.

Your parameter line should look something like this:

```
.add(new OleDbParameter("@strname", strName))
```

For OleDB queries, it is important to realize that the parameters are actually ignoring the name `@strname` and just updating the parameter information in index order.  So the order in which the parameters appear in the sql statement have to be in the same order you supply the parameters.

Comment: insert into dbo.Event(ID, Name, Summary, Date) values (NEWID(),

Comment: thanks, makes sense
As I'm using '" & strName & "' in my code, does this change anything, tried all possible ways (("@strname", strName), ("@strname", '"strName"'), ("@strname", & strName &)) and get a different error for each :S

Comment: @Monkey When you mention an error, it is always helpful to tell us exactly what the error is.  I assume `strName` is a variable in your code that holds the value of something that you want save.  If `NewID()` is a function you created in VB.Net, you would have to pass that in as a parameter, too.  It looks like you are using SQL Server, so you should probably be using the SQL-Objects, not the OleDB-Objects.  That would require a change in connection strings, too.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Lars except you are missing the fact that the sql is wrong.  Here is a more complete example.

```
    Dim sql = <value>insert into dbo.Event(ID, Name, Summary, Date) values (NEWID(),@Name,@Summary,@Date)</value>

    Using connection As OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        Using command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql.Value, connection)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", nameValue)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Summary", summaryValue)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateValue)

            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
```

If you want to not bother with ADO and are looking for something simpler I recommend using Simple.Data http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/.  It is by far one of the simplest ways to interact with a database without having to now SQL or ADO but it certainly does help.

Good Luck